# Tomcat 7 getting CreateJavaVM Failed Error

Tags: apache, jvm, tomcat7, permgen

I have an Apache tomcat 7.0.5 Server on a Windows R2 Server and I've deployed a webApp ( java JSF) on it, everything was working fine, but it suddenly stopped and won't run again. when I try to run it, it tells me "Error 1067: The Process terminated unexpectedly" and In the logs I get these files:

tomcat7-stdout.2012-08-08.log

```
2012-08-08 18:00:06 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

commons-daemon.2012-08-08.log

```
[2012-08-08 19:02:30] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2012-08-08 19:13:02] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.4.0 64-bit) started
[2012-08-08 19:13:02] [info]  Running 'Tomcat7' Service...
[2012-08-08 19:13:02] [info]  Starting service...
[2012-08-08 19:13:02] [error] CreateJavaVM Failed
[2012-08-08 19:13:03] [info]  Service started in 1000 ms.
[2012-08-08 19:13:03] [info]  Run service finished.
[2012-08-08 19:13:03] [info]  Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

tomcat7-stderr.2012-08-08.log

```
2012-08-08 18:00:06 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError '
```

since I was having some 'perm gen' memory error I added some stuff  to my apache Tomcat properties, folowing this link  [how to handle Perm Gen](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/03/12/solving-tomcat-outofmemoryerror-heap-space-and-permgen-space/)

so my Java Options look like this:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\logging.properties
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Any ideas as to why the server won't start anymore? THANKS!

~Myy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spending hours trying to figure this out, I finally found it. I had an extra space at the end of VM command.

```
 '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError '
```

which was giving me the Unrecognized VM option.....

Thanks for reading, hopefully when you get this error, you can take extra precautions to verify the syntax.

Comment: I also got the same problem with a space before the option

Comment: This answer combined with a tip from another site suggesting running Tomcat from the command prompt instead of as a Windows service just fixed a similar issue for me when we went from Java 11 to 16. The tomcat logs were not showing any clue as to why the Java VM couldn't be created, but running from the cmd prompt threw "Unrecognized VM Option 'AggressiveOpts'. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

to manage the memory you need to set some Xms and Xmx parameter

- Xms manages the initial heap size
- Xmx manages the maximum heap size

Thus try to add :

```
-Xms=256m -Xmx=256m
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

The error is on option "HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" which is not even listed in your post. Can you post a screen print of the "Java" tab from the "tomcat" service screen (similar to the link you have provided) ? This will tell us the actual options you are using and also the memory you have set.

Answer (score 0):

copy the file msvcr71.dll from the bin dir of your java installation, to the bin dir of the tomcat installation.